# Trying to get Multiple Tabs to display in Attributes Table in CMV viewer javascript file

Tags: fields-attributes, configurable-map-viewer, search, widget

My first tab displays correctly..

This is my code in my viewer:
[image]

Both the service URLS display the attributes table in ArcMap correctly and both the URLS work in a browser

This is the error message i get from growler when attempting to load the second tab the search seems to fail..

I get a Search Error msg that displays saying "Sorry, an error occurred and your search could not be completed." then the message disappears....

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received suggests that there was an error executing the query on the ArcGIS Server. You can use the Dev Tools of your browser (Chrome preferred) to determine the actual URL including the full query parameters that is sent to the server. If you open that url in your browser, it will hopefully provide you were more details as to what the issue is. You can also check the ArcGIS Server logs for perhaps some more info.